# Hiding image URL

Tags: php, html

Using shadowbox, I am displaying my images onto the screen like this:

```
<img src="images/thumbpic.jpg" width="100px" />
```

However I am looking for way to mask the image so that the URL path is not displayed. Otherwise the user will be able to access the image directly, by typing the URL into their address bar.

How can I do this?

Comment: There is a million ways to get hold of the image even if you disable hotlinking like suggested by Peter Kiss. Since the browser needs access to the image resource to display it, all approaches to keeping it from doing that will be imperfect.

Comment: It doesn't matter what you do, I can always right-click->Save Image As... or hit my PrtSc button. Don't need to even see the URL.

Comment: You need to get over hiding the image source. A web page is essentially sending that content to that persons computer. What you are asking is like how can I email someone an attachment but not let them save it. This is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible at all, since it's all client side and there's always a way to get that image. Same answer is  for CSS & JS.

Disabling a hotlinking wouldn't help you, since this case has nothing to do with it (because you said `by typing the URL into their address bar`).

Comment: Well, as suggested by Peter Kiss, you *can* disable hotlinking which will go a long way.

Comment: @Pekka he can, but as I wrote in my answer, there are work-arounds for it, too.

Comment: @Martin: it will help stop 90-95% of hotlinking. There are always workarounds, that does not mean you should not limit the damage (so to say)

Comment: @nice anyway, this isn't about hotlinking. He said `by typing the URL into their address bar.`

Comment: @Martin: I still consider that hotlinking. You can call it direct linking if you wish.

Comment: @nico but you have no way to restrict it, since you can just press right button and press "Show image" which sents exact refferer which has been sent before

Comment: @martin: no, there is no way to absolutely restrict it, but the average user ignores how to bypass these simple restrictions.

Comment: @nico but with your solution, normal user don't know how to ALLOW to send refferer. Some browsers/firewalls disable sending a refferer

Comment: @Martin: I am just answering the question that was asked by the OP with probably the only possible (partial) solution. Whether that poses accessibility problems is a completely different issue, that I am absolutely not denying.

Comment: nico, checked the link out, however <img src="images/thumbpic.jpg" width="100px" /> , when you block direct url using that script, how will the browser differentiate betweena php script accessing it directly with a user typing in the url in their address bar?

Answer (score 1):

You could embed the image directly in the page. You then can't hotlink it and it would only be accessible from that page.

Here's an example: http://www.sweeting.org/mark/blog/2005/07/12/base64-encoded-images-embedded-in-html

Though, I don't believe this is supported on all browsers yet.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent direct access to the images you should restrict the access to the images rather than trying to hide their URL.

To do this you can, for instance, modify your `.htaccess` file (a tool to generate an .htaccess file for this purpose can be found [here](http://www.htaccesstools.com/hotlink-protection/)).

In any case remember that the user can always (no matter what you do) save the images on his computer, you cannot prevent that, as the image is downloaded on the client when he visits your sites.

Comment: As I said in my previous comment, this is NOT about hotlinking at all. Read his question/my comment again

Comment: @Martin.: I am speaking of preventing direct access to the image, which is what the OP wants.

Comment: @Martin This answer provides a solution in the link. Not allowing blank referers will stop people from getting the image by typing the URL in the browser, which is exactly what the OP wants. Now that said, it's a bad solution as referer checks are not reliable and easily worked around, but it's a "solution" nonetheless.

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys, how can i achieve this in iis, does anyone know. All the material i have found, has been for apache

Comment: @bobo2000: that's because it's a problem that you can (partially) solve by configuring your webserver, it has nothing to do with HTML or PHP. Have you checked the link I provided? Just add the .htaccess file to your directory and that's it.

Comment: IIS7 does not support .htaccess files, I think you could find modules that can allow it to use .htaccess files, but I never used them.